# How to Replace values in a pd dataframe column based on a condition with a range of values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, replace

I have a [data set](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/insaid2018/Term-1/master/Data/Projects/matches.csv) which has a column name 'id'. Now in this column all the values should be 1 to 696 in sequence, but values after 636 are 7*** something, I want to replace all these values and bring them in range 637 to 696. How can I do that? I tried replace, .loc, where etc. but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you share your code and the expected inputs and outputs

Comment: Are these replaced values supposed to follow a pattern, or just random between 637 and 696?

Comment: Can you apply the same operation to all whose values (for example, substract X to them?). If so, you could try this: df[df['id']>636]['id'] = df[df['id']>636]['id'] - X

Comment: @CeliusStingher they should be in a sequence 637, 638, upto 696.

Comment: @maxi.marufo cant apply same operation, value of X would be different for each value i want to obtain.

Comment: Final question, 7*** where *** represent random numbers?

Comment: @CeliusStingher yes any number which is grater than 696 basically, all the values in this column should be 1, 2, 3, .... upto 696. you can say its like index starting at 1 ending at 696.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, re-assign *id* for sequential integers using [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
df = (pd.read_csv("/path/to/data.csv")
        .assign(id = np.arange(1,697))
     )
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
df['id'] = range(1,len(df)+1)
```

if you want it to start on 0, do:

```
df['id'] = range(len(df))
```